# Асинхронный буфер обмена

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Можно ли как-то установить асинхронно буфер обмена?

```js
function copy(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", Math.random());
  
  e.value = window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');
}

function async_copy(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", Math.random());
    e.value = window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');
  });
}
```

```html
<input oncopy='copy(this)' value='copy'>
<input oncopy='async_copy(this)' value='async copy'>
```

Comment: При `setTimeout` теряется событие, поэтому не получается задать асинхронно буфер. Создавать невидимый `input` в `DOM` со значением и использовать `execCommand('copy')` пробовал, ничего не вышло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в том, что теряется событие. Событие никуда не теряется. В целях безопасности работать с буфером обмена можно только из потока, который был инициирован пользователем событиями  `cut`, `copy` или `paste`.

`setTimeout` уже не инициирован пользователем.

Пример, где событие есть, но данные в буфер обмена все равно не записываются и не считываются.

```js
function copy(e) {
  console.log(event);
  event.preventDefault();
  event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", Math.random());
  var txt = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
  console.log(txt);
  e.value = txt;
}

function async_copy(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", Math.random());
    var txt = e.clipboardData.getData('text');
    console.log(txt);
    e.target.value = txt;

  });
}
```

```html
<input oncopy='copy(this)' value='copy'>
<input oncopy='async_copy(event)' value='async copy'>
```

Comment: Так что, асинхронно буфер обмена никак не задать?

Comment: @Mr.Black Нет, никак. И слава богу, что никак. А то представьте, заходите на сайт, а он считывает данные из вашего буфера обмена. А ведь там может храниться секретная информация!

Comment: Ну да, верно. Согласен)